# How to find the sum of each group which is grouped by another group?

Tags: oracle, plsql, group-by, oracle-analytics

I am actually trying to make a matrix table using Oracle Analytics tool and PL/SQL.

Let's say i have a query which has in select statement variables Employee, Description, orderid ,amount and is grouped by Employee, Description. Orderid and amount belong to the same group. From this query i want extract the sum of the amount of each description from all employees. Do you have any idea how i can do this?

Thank you.

Edit:
Let's say we have the following query:

```
Select Employee, Description, orderid ,amount
  From Employees
 Group by Employee,Description
```

I want to extract the sum of amount from each Description group but from all Employees.A way to do this could be like this:

```
Select Description,sum(amount)
  From Employees
 Group by Description
```

But the actual query is much more complex and if i choose to make another query for finding the sum of each description i have to link it somehow to the first query to be able to show the results at the report.
Do you have any idea of a way to do this through oracle analytics publisher?

Thank you.

Comment: Coult you edit the post, present with the example table with the data and the query that you would like to extend?

Comment: I edited the post.

Comment: The first query is not going to work, because with Group BY you can only use columns that you are aggregating by, and aggregation functions like SUM or COUNT (that is, orderid and amount cannot be added to the query results, however you can add SUM(amount))

Comment: paste that complex query, so we could help you out. As someone stated, you have to use aggregate functions for columns not included in group by clause.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are trying to achieve. I think your example is too simple to get the help you need. You have mentioned you are trying to build a matrix, so I don't know if a more proper example would be a table of employees paychecks, for example:
[EmployeeID, PayDate, JobPerformed, Amount]:{[100;2022/01/31;Secretary;1200,00],[100;2022/02/28;Accountant;1200,00],[100;2022/02/28;Secretary;500,00],[101;2022/01/31;IT;1200,00],[101;2022/02/28;Secretary;1200,00]}
And you want this as result:[EmpID;Accountant;IT;Secretary]:{[100;1200,00;0;1700,00],[101;0;1200,00;1200,00]}

Comment: I want something like the example you posted Ana GH and specifically the sum of amounts of each Job Performed. Thanks everyone who replied so far.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select coalesce(Employee,'ALL_EMPOYEES'), coalesce(Description,'ALL_DESCRIPTION'), orderid ,amount
  From Employees
 Group by ROLLUP (Employee,Description)


Select coalesce(Employee,'ALL_EMPOYEES'), coalesce(Description,'ALL_DESCRIPTION'), orderid ,amount
  From Employees
 Group by CUBE (Employee,Description)
```